What's the difference between ql.Euribor, ql.Libor, ql.Iborindex? like are their calculation share the same machanism?
# Here is the code below, I use different function calculate the answer, and their result are different.

# Define the evaluation date
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(23, 9, 2024)
 
# Set notional and coupon rate
notional = 1000000
coupon_rate = 0.02
 
# Set dates for cash flow testing
start_date = ql.Date(23, 9, 2023)
end_date = ql.Date(23, 9, 2025)
 
# Schedule setup for the fixed leg (semi-annual payments)
calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond)  # Specify the market type
schedule = ql.Schedule(start_date, end_date, ql.Period(ql.Semiannual),
                       calendar, ql.ModifiedFollowing, ql.ModifiedFollowing, 
                       ql.DateGeneration.Forward, False)
 
# Set up a fixed-rate bond for comparison
fixed_leg = ql.FixedRateLeg(schedule, ql.Actual360(), [notional], [coupon_rate])
 
# Create discount curve (constant flat rate for simplicity)
flat_rate = ql.FlatForward(0, ql.NullCalendar(), ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.03)), ql.Actual360())
discount_curve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(flat_rate)
 
# Compare ql.IborIndex, ql.Euribor, ql.Libor
# 1. IborIndex (3-month USD)
ibor_index = ql.IborIndex("Ibor", ql.Period(3, ql.Months), 2, ql.USDCurrency(), calendar, ql.ModifiedFollowing, False, ql.Actual360(), discount_curve)
 
# 2. Euribor (3-month)
euribor_index = ql.Euribor3M(discount_curve)
 
# 3. Libor (3-month USD)
libor_index = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period(3, ql.Months), discount_curve)
 
# Extract forward rates from each index
ibor_rate = ibor_index.fixing(ql.Date(23, 9, 2024))
euribor_rate = euribor_index.fixing(ql.Date(23, 9, 2024))
libor_rate = libor_index.fixing(ql.Date(23, 9, 2024))
 
print(f"Ibor Index Rate: {ibor_rate}")
print(f"Euribor Rate: {euribor_rate}")
print(f"Libor Rate: {libor_rate}")

# output:
'''
Ibor Index Rate: 0.03011529445304053
Euribor Rate: 0.030116550895258113
Libor Rate: 0.030116550895258113
'''
```


IborIndex is the generic base class.  Euribor and USDLibor specialize it by specifying the fixing calendar, the day count convention and all the other parameters you're passing to the IborIndex constructor in your example.  The calculations are inherited from IborIndex and are the same for all three.
The slight difference you see is due to the fact that the fixing calendar for USD LIBOR is (or, I should say, was) a combination of the US calendar and of the UK calendar, where the LIBOR was fixed.  Thus, when asked for the fixing for September 23, your ibor_index will forecast the rate from September 25 to December 26 (because Dec. 25, Christmas, is a US holiday) while libor_index will forecast the rate from September 25 to December 27 (because Dec. 25 and 26 are both holidays in the UK).
